# why colors change in chrome dark mode while in other dark mode extensions don't?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I was changing my border color in my project and realized some colors aren't right, after testing it on other browsers and different situations, I realized these colors transition are because of dark mode, but after testing it with different dark mode extensions I found out colors only change in chrome default dark mode, so I was wondering does anybody know what's going on under the hood and why chrome default(the one you set in chrome://flags/-->Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents-->enabled) behaves differently from other dark mode extensions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

images above are captured in light mode and dark extensions except chrome default dark mode
(black(#000), white(#fff), blue from top to bottom order)

[image]

[image]

[image]

images above are captured in chrome default dark mode
(black(#000), white(#fff), blue from top to bottom order)

Comment: If I say: _"I like you but those other people don't."_, wouldn't your first reaction be: _"Which other people?"_? Same with your question. Which other extensions? I'm also missing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can see this phenomenon for myself because those images, without any code, don't clarify much.

Comment: the code doesn't have anything to do with this question...and for dark mode extensions I mean: any , but for instance you can use dark reader...

Comment: It's not [a programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if the code has nothing to do with it.

Comment: yeah, you can't see I'm asking about quantum physics....@KIKOSoftware